# MongoDB sum with match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with the following data structure:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  text: 'This contains some text',
  type: 'one',
  category: {
     name: 'Testing',
     slug: 'test'
  },
  state: 'active'
}
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is get a list of categories and counts.  I'm using the following:

```
  const query = [
    {
      $match: {
        state: 'active'
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        categories: 1
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$categories'
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { category: '$categories.name', slug: '$categories.slug' },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }
  ]
```

This returns all categories (that are active) and the total counts for documents matching each category.

The problem is that I want to introduce two additional `$match` that should still return all the unique categories, but only affect the counts.  For example, I'm trying to add a text search (which is indexed on the `text` field) and also a match for `type`.

I can't do this at the top of the pipeline because it would then only return categories that match, not only affect the `$sum`.  So basically it would be like being able to add a `$match` within the `$group` only for the `$sum`.  Haven't been able to find a solution for this and any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: can you provide sample of expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) inside of your `$group` statement:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: { category: '$categories.name', slug: '$categories.slug' },
        count: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$categories.type", "one" ] }, 1, 0 ] } }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good however I don't believe I can do a `$text` search within `$cond`?

Comment: Yes, $text is a bit specific so you probably need to run a separate query just for `$text`